# jpa2 force em to refresh a field setted like insertable=false

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I am working with jpa 2.0 and I have a field in a table of the database that has value by default, I put that field in my definition of entities as insertable = false so that when inserted retain the default value, the insert is done correctly but when requery the object that field is null in the entity, however, that it has been inserted correctly.

This is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SOME_TABLE")
public class SomeTable implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private SomeTablePK id;

@Column(name="X1")
private String x1;

**@Column(name="X2", insertable=false)**
private Date x2;

... more fields....

... setters and getters...
}
```

there any way to force the entity manager to refresh the value of the field that I used as insertable = false? or what can i do to fix it?

Thank you very much.

PS. It is important to mention that in my persistence.xml and place the following line to disable the cache.

```
<properties>
<property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="NONE"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to invoke manually the refresh after the flush operation.

The Spec (**3.2.4 Synchronization to the Database**) says that:

> The state of persistent entities is synchronized to the database at transaction commit. This synchroniza- tion involves writing to the database any updates to persistent entities and their relationships as speci- fied above.
>
> An update to the state of an entity includes both the assignment of a new value to a persistent property or field of the entity as well as the modification of a mutable value of a persistent property or field[28].

Pay attention below:

> **Synchronization to the database does not involve a refresh of any managed entities unless the refresh operation is explicitly invoked on those entities or cascaded to them as a result of the specification of the cascade=REFRESH or cascade=ALL annotation element value.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the field that has the default value is a field that has no constraint, where or how I place the annotation cascade = REFRESH ??? 

Thnx again!

Comment: An annotation will not work but itself, you will need to invoke the `entityManager.refresh(YOU_ENTITY)`. The cascade annotation will work only for the entity relation ships.

Comment: hello again, thanks for the reply, when I try to make the refresh after the persist the entity says "EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists", I'm using jpa within an EJB, how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello, i found the answer!!!! i just have to do: em.persist(entityObj); em.flush(); em.refresh(entityObj); for more explanation to everybody can consult: http://www.hascode.com/2013/02/adding-multiple-entitylisteners-to-an-entity-in-jpa-2/, anyway uaiHebert Thanks for being a light in the road, certainly, your site and your posts are amazing, a pleasure!!!